# PHP Own Payment Transaction Fee

Tags: php, paypal, transactions

I HAVE FOUND A SOLUTION FOR ANYONE WHO IS WONDERING HOW TO CHARGE A TRANSACTION FEE:

On the PayPal IPN form simply add

```
 <input type="hidden" name="handling" value="[amount extra]">
```

---

I currently have a PHP script with 3 plans and the service is where users sign up and sell products. Currently my code works by going through PayPal and then they purchase a product but with the free plan, I'm not making money back for storage etc so I want to charge a transaction fee but am unable to find anything helpful online. I had a go at experimenting by coding it myself but it just didn't work so I thought I'd ask for some pointers from the best coding community.

```
**select buy now** > check price and work out 2% fee and deduct from sellers profit and send to company account (only if on free plan) > go to **paypal and get product**
```

The bits in * mean I have already coded and go it to work I'm just having trouble with the middle step, all help much appreciated.

The code I tried is

```
deduct = '2%'
if{
$sellerprice = actual
$transaction = deduct

$total = number_format($sellerprice - $transaction 2);}
else{
header('Location: $paypal_url');
}
```

as you can tell it doesn't really make sense and I was just playing around.

Comment: Go ahead and post what you tried and explain what exactly didn't work so that we can help you work through it.